# Is it possible to make TypeScript crash on 0 / 0 and Math.log(-1) instead of returning NaN?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, nan, typechecking

I was under the impression that I could trust Flow or TypeScript to protect me from NaN errors, but this is not true.

Here is a PoC repository that demonstrates the problem: https://github.com/ndbroadbent/typescript-experiments

```
const testFunction = (a: number, b: number) => {
  if (a > b) {
    return;
  } else if (a < b) {
    return;
  } else if (a === b) {
    return;
  } else {
    throw new Error("Unreachable code");
  }
}
```

This function works fine when called with:

```
testFunction(1, 2);
```

But the following calls will throw an error:

```
testFunction(1, 0 / 0);

testFunction(1, Math.log(-1));

testFunction(1, Math.sqrt(-2));

testFunction(1, parseFloat('string'));
```

You might say that this is the "correct" behavior, but I'd much rather write code that doesn't need to handle any NaN values. I want to have a runtime error as soon as JavaScript tries to call `0 / 0` or `Math.log(-1)`, so that my error report is easy to understand and I can fix the actual problem. When `NaN` is propagated through your code and crashes in some random place, it can be difficult to find the source.

It should be easy to override `Math.log` and `Math.sqrt` to crash whenever the result would be `NaN`. And I could probably write a Babel plugin that converts `a / b` into something like `assertNotNaN(a / b)`, or even `safeDivide(a, b)`. (I also want to throw a divide-by-zero error instead of returning Infinity.)

Are there any other functions that I would need to override or transpile?

Note that with TypeScript, I only need to care about math operations that can return `NaN`. TypeScript will prevent type errors like `{} + 1`.

Comment: `Math.pow(99999999, 99999999);`

Comment: I think the best you could do, is just do a `Math.isFinite()` check.

Comment: I don't think you can make `0 / 0` cause an exception in the same way that you can't make `3 + 2` cause an exception. How about defining a function `myDivision(a, b)` that would do this for you?

Comment: @jlh Yeah that's a good idea. I might be interested in writing a Babel plugin that can convert all divisions into a "safeDivision" call that throws an error instead returning NaN. I've also opened this issue for TypeScript: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28682